# NodeJS MySQL Query results to [object Object]

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have this code:

```
var sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT sensor_id, timestamp FROM Displacement_Record WHERE wave_type = 1 ORDER BY timestamp ASC";
var sql2 = "SELECT timestamp FROM Displacement_Record WHERE wave_type = 0 AND sensor_id = ?";
var sql3 = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM Sensor_Record WHERE sensor_id = ?";
var pTime, sTime;

db.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.query(sql1, function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            var sensor = res[i].sensor_id;
            console.log(sensor);
            var pTime = res[i].timestamp;
            sql2 = mysql.format(sql2, sensor);
            conn.query(sql2, function (err, results, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var sTime = res[i].timestamp; //timestamp error
                console.log("results = " + results + " " + results.length);
                conn.query(sql3, function (err, res, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    var location = [res[i].latitude, res[i].longitude];
                    console.log("Data = " + sensor + " " + pTime + " " + sTime + " " + latitude + " " + longitude);
                });
            });
        }
    });
    conn.release();
});
```

The first query give me the results properly. I am able to get and store the data I need. However, the second and third query results as:

```
results = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

and throws:

```
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined
```

I tried to see what causes this. I am able to get a proper result only when I remove the condition in the query. However, I need the condition of course. And I'm also wondering how come it throws error in the following queries when I am able to get results on the first query, with conditions and all.

I hope somebody can help me, thanks!

Comment: One missing thing, at least, is sql3 parameters replace: `sql3 = mysql.format(sql3, sensor);`

Comment: There is no reason the script crashes at `var pTime = res[i].timestamp;` if it can read `var sensor = res[i].sensor_id;` try rewriting the line, a unexpected character may have popped before ` res[i]`, an irregular white-space for example

Comment: I edited the code in question. There was actually a `var sTime = res[i].timestamp;` in the second query.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually not really a problem. when you have `[object Object]` in any console.log, it means that what you want to print in a string is not possible to print **as** a string.

If you really want to print the result, what you should do instead of

```js
conn.query(sql2, function (err, results, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("results = " + results + " " + results.length); // HERE
    conn.query(sql3, function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var location = [res[i].latitude, res[i].longitude];
        console.log("Data = " + sensor + " " + pTime + " " + sTime + " " + latitude  + " " + longitude); // HERE
    });
});
```

Is actually :

```js
conn.query(sql2, function (err, results, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("results ="); // HERE
    console.log({ results }, results.length); // HERE
    conn.query(sql3, function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var location = [res[i].latitude, res[i].longitude];
        console.log("Data = "); // HERE
        console.log({ sensor, pTime, sTime, latitude, longitude }); // HERE
    });
});
```

See the notation `console.log({ variable });`
This allows you to log your variable content, with the key displayed on the left, as you'd actually want to do in your current console.logs.

Example :

```js
const results = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const randomString = 'Some content in here';

console.log({ results, randomString});
```

This outputs : 
[image]

Comment: See my comment on your post concerning the Exception @nelaaam

Comment: Oh I was able to see that I get the results. But how do I store it to a variable? It still throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined. Is my way of getting the data (res[i].latitude) incorrect?

Comment: Look at the params of the function. Your `res` reference is no longer the one you are iterating on, but the variable you have in your function callback. (at `conn.query(sql3, function (err, res, fields) {`)

Comment: I already tried changing the variable name but it still gives me the error.

Comment: Then it is probably a scope problem. Try storing your first callback parameter in a variable before entering in another callback.

Comment: It was the variable i. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer to your post

Answer (score 1):

You can't console combination of string and object at once time.

Try below format, It might help you.

```
console.log('results =');
console.log(results);
console.log(results.length);
```